# mysql Search a string in table column having different order

Tags: mysql

i have a column in mysql table having strings like 'dubai the-ritz hotel united arab emirates'
i want to select this column if the search string is 'dubai rit' or 'united arab emirates rit' or 'rit dubai'
if words are in any order i want to select this column as i can see it has the word. i tried using mysql 'like' and mysql FULLTEXT search but i am unable to perform the get the accurate results

```
SELECT * FROM `table`  where SearchString like 'dubai rit'

select * from table WHERE MATCH(SearchString) AGAINST('dubai rit' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

any help please.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `*` to search partial words:

```
..
AGAINST('+dubai* +rit*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )
```

You can add * to every word from whatever programming language you're using to query MySql.

PS: MySql only allows prefix, means you can only add * at the end of the word.

[Reference: Section *](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html)

Comment: thank you fore reply. it returns this also "Dubai Avari Dubai united arab emirates" which i don't want. i wanted to show  'dubai the-ritz hotel united arab emirates'  based on 'dubai rit'

Comment: Try with this: `('+dubai* +rit*' IN BOOLEAN MODE )`

Comment: thank you sir. just last thing for ( '+united arab emirates* +av*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) it also return 'Stratford Manor Stratford-upon-Avon United Kingdom' how we can make this work to return only "united arab emirates and av"

Comment: `united arab emirates` are logically 3 different words, not 1. I hope you got the point :)

Comment: AGAINST('+united* +arab* +emirates* +av*' IN BOOLEAN MODE ) worked. thank you so much. so nice of you. you are  a STAR

Comment: sir can you please look into this. i m trying to do same thing but if the data is in array and i wanted to do search using php
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440856/php-search-a-string-in-array-with-different-order-of-words