# PHP search a string in array with different order of words

Tags: php, arrays, search

i have an index in array having strings like 'dubai the-ritz hotel united arab emirates' i want to select this index if the search string is 'dubai rit' or 'united arab emirates rit' or 'rit dubai' if words are in any order i want to select this index as i can see it has the word. i know normal array_search will not work here

the following will not work

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
or 

$arr = [
    'foo'    => 'bar',
    'abc'    => 'def',
    'bool'   => true,
    'target' => 'xyz'
];

var_dump( array_search( 'xyz', $arr ) );
```

Comment: Take a look at `preg_grep()` to get the elements matching your partial string. After that you can get the key from it.

Comment: Can you please see this question. basically i wanted to do same thing on array rather than on db. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39440099/mysql-search-a-string-in-table-column-having-different-order

Comment: loop, strpos .. terribly inefficient. a db would be better

Comment: i have a db solution but is there any way of making it faster

Comment: @bilalrabbi
Yes - optimizing your database query. It will not work if you will use array for this.